# How to make text color to change in a table when drop down list changes in another cell

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet which I need help with. Characteristics:

- I have a drop down menu in column C.
- I have a dates from column F to J (5 days).
- I have 15 rows (names) from row 8 to 22.
- F to J is to determine staff productive for a day/week.

I need F8 to J22, to change text colour to green when 15 or above is entered. If below 15 I need the text to be orange depending on what is selected in the drop down menu in C.

So If I have item "STU ENT" selected in C, I need text in F8 to J22 to be green when 15 or above is entered. If below I need orange.

If "STU EXP" is selected in C, I need text in F8 to J22 to be green when above 8, orange when below.

I can get it to work with conditional formatting but only when 15 is entered for all drop down menu items, but I need this to be different for each selection in the drop down list...

Help would be so great and save me so much time.

Thanks in advance.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwn4b.jpg)

I've tried formulas in conditional formatting, but can't get it to meet my what i need.

I have looked at VBA coding, but don't want to run macros.

Comment: May you provide a screenshot, please?

Comment: thanks for the response. I have added a screenshot of the first few lines. Drop down list is in the SKILL tag Column and has about 10 options. each of these have a different value i need to turn to green that number is achieved in the date columns. eg for STU ENT i need the number to go green when 15 is entered. if under 15 is entered i need it orange. If i select STU EST i need it green when 8 is entered, under 8 i need orange. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with Conditional formatting.

Create a new cell with the formula (for example M1):

```
=IF(C1="STU ENT",15,8)
```

I understand there are only 2 options for Column C ("STU ENT" and "STU EXP") and that the value is only in 1 cell that changes from one another.

Then do the conditional formatting referring to M1 cell instead of a value.